# How to calculate covariance in PhP for arrays of different sizes?

Tags: php, statistics, covariance, quantitative-finance

This function computes the covariance of two arrays of the same size (e.g., `$countA=$countB=20`).

How could it be expanded for arrays of different sizes? (For instance, to calculate based on the size of smaller array, if `$countA=10` and `$countB=12`? How low the smaller array could be and still would make statistical sense?)

Thanks a million!

M

```
function getCovariance($valuesA, $valuesB){
  $countA=count($valuesA);
  $countB=count($valuesB);
  if($countA != $countB){
    trigger_error('Arrays with different sizes: countA='. $countA .', countB='. $countB, E_USER_WARNING);
    return false;
  }

  if($countA < 0){
    trigger_error('Empty arrays', E_USER_WARNING);
    return false;
  }

  // Use library function if available
  if(function_exists('stats_covariance')){
    return stats_covariance($valuesA, $valuesB);
  }

  $meanA=array_sum($valuesA) / floatval($countA);
  $meanB=array_sum($valuesB) / floatval($countB);
  $add=0.0;

  for ($pos=0; $pos < $countA; $pos++){
    $valueA=$valuesA[ $pos ];
    if(!is_numeric($valueA)){
      trigger_error('Not numerical value in array A at position '. $pos .', value='. $valueA, E_USER_WARNING);
      return false;
    }

    $valueB=$valuesB[ $pos ];
    if(!is_numeric($valueB)){
      trigger_error('Not numerical value in array B at position '. $pos .', value='. $valueB, E_USER_WARNING);
      return false;
    }

    $difA=$valueA - $meanA;
    $difB=$valueB - $meanB;
    $add += ($difA * $difB);
  }

  return $add / floatval($countA);
}
```

Comment: So if you have one array with 10 and one with 12 you want to use the first 10 items of both arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the min() to find which array has the fewest items and slice them both at that number of items.

```
function getCovariance($valuesA, $valuesB){
  // sizing both arrays the same, if different sizes, @Andreas @stackoverflow
  $no_keys = min(count($valuesA), count($valuesB));
  $valuesA = array_slice($valuesA, 0, $no_keys);
  $valuesB = array_slice($valuesB, 0, $no_keys);

  // if size of arrays is too small
  if($no_keys<2){return 0.0000000000001;}

  // Use library function if available
  if(function_exists('stats_covariance')){return stats_covariance($valuesA, $valuesB);}

  $meanA=array_sum($valuesA)/$no_keys;
  $meanB=array_sum($valuesB)/$no_keys;
  $add=0.0;

  for ($pos=0; $pos < $no_keys; $pos++){
    $valueA=$valuesA[ $pos ];
    if(!is_numeric($valueA)){
      trigger_error('Not numerical value in array A at position '. $pos .', value='. $valueA, E_USER_WARNING);
      return false;
    }

    $valueB=$valuesB[ $pos ];
    if(!is_numeric($valueB)){
      trigger_error('Not numerical value in array B at position '. $pos .', value='. $valueB, E_USER_WARNING);
      return false;
    }

    $difA=$valueA - $meanA;
    $difB=$valueB - $meanB;
    $add += ($difA * $difB);
  }

  return $add/$no_keys;
}
```

Comment: @Emma No problem. Just to be clear, because we make the array counts the same your code that checks if the arrays are not the same count is not needed. Both $countA and $countB will be the same, they are both the same as $no_keys. Meaning you can replace all $countA/B with $no_keys. Then `$meanA=array_sum($valuesA) / floatval($countA);` $countA is coming from count() which returns an integer, why floatval it?